# Objective-C : How to redefine methods in CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category, redefinition

I need to redefine one method in CGGeometry.h file (in CoreGraphics framework).
You cannot do it by using Category or extension cuz it is not Objective-C class..
You will have an error.

I'm trying to redefine this function in **CGGeometry.h**

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; rect.size.height = height;
  NSLog(@"bla bla bla");
  return rect;
}
```

It should call my new Extended function in all over the scope of the whole project...

I can change the original source code of the CoreGraphics,
but it will be related to all **other** projects.. I don't wont to do it that way...
I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Thank you.

Comment: is "`CGRectMake`" being called only in code that you own, or are there other third party or commercial frameworks that you are using?  If it's all your own stuff, why not make a new method named "`iUserRectMake`" or something like that and then call ***that***?  You might also try doing '`#undef CGRectMake`" and then "`#define CGRectMake iUserRectMake`" to replace it (not 100% if that would work, though).

Comment: This is not a method, it's a function. You are trying to [interpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526882/interposing-of-os-x-system-calls), which is not as easy as overriding a method.

Comment: I am using Cocos2d. This project already exist, and now I'm trying to modify it.. There are few hundreds or thousands calls this Function CGRectMake.. I can do it by Find-Replace ... But I was wondering if there is some more correct solution ?